# Image manipulation on the server or client side?

Tags: javascript, python, django, image, image-processing

I'm developing a web application based on Django and I need online image manipulation. I want to allow the user to upload their images, manipulate them (crop, filters, re-order, etc) and send them to my server.

My question is: should I manage this image manipulation on the server using or on the client-side?

You can get some example from this website: printstudio.io

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you need the user to be able to manipulate images, so it would be more efficient to allow them to do so, client side.

**For Client-Side**:
There are a few JavaScript libraries available. FabricJS and CamanJS use the `<canvas>` element to provide image manipulation capabilities. CamanJS should be sufficient for your needs.

It is recommended you do not do the image processing server-side, but here are some libraries for that purpose, for information's sake.

**For Server Side**: Use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/index.html) server side, which is a fork of PIL - the Python Imaging Library.

It is one of best image manipulation tools, which can perform the cropping, making thumbnails, etc that your website requires.

I have used it in on a server and then uploaded it to S3.

Comment: Hey Vaibhav, what I need is to give the user the chance to edit their own images on the website and then send them to me.

Comment: Okay, Then best way to do is client-side and your server will just stored the images.

Comment: Great. Any suggestions on which library to use?

Comment: There are huge library in JS, Utilize the HTML 5 Canvas and You can [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com) or [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/). CommanJS will be good.